# How to detect HTML form changes using jQuery, in detail for a noob?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm kind of a noob on HTML.  I've sifted thru [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959670/generic-way-to-detect-if-html-form-is-edited), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311663/find-out-if-html-form-has-changed), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759718/how-to-detect-a-change-in-any-of-a-forms-input-fields-using-jquery), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025396/how-do-you-handle-a-form-change-in-jquery), and more.  Here's the code I came up with but it, and many more experiments I've done, do not work.  I can pound on my input fields all day and I never see the alert.  Most answers assume you know something that I guess I don't know.  Can anyone tell me what may be wrong?

```
<script   
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $("#myform :input").change(function() {
        alert("Form changed");
    });
</script>

<form id="myform" name="myform" method="GET">
   <!-- a bunch of text fields, etc -->
</form>
```

Comment: `:input` will select all the elements with `type=input` in the `#myForm`. Is that what you want to achieve? Be specific for your question.

Comment: I guess your question was the correct question.  I was using built-in "inputs" from cakephp, I guess they're HTML inputs.  All my buttons were called inputs but I guess button click events don't count as changes.  Hence no "changes were detected".  But also I did indeed have to move part of the script below the form as Jason L suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="field">
    <input type="text" name="field2">
    <input type="text" name="field3">
</form>

<script>
    $("#myform input").change(function() {
        alert("Form changed");
    });
</script>
```

Try this.  Make sure your script is below the form or the form won't be loaded when the script runs.  Or you could wrap your javascript in `$(document).ready()`.  This will execute your code once the DOM is loaded.  https://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your Javascript
}
```

Also, if you are looking for the alert to fire on each keypress, take a look at `keyup()` or `keydown()` instead of using `change()` in jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: Note that if you merely want to detect whether the form has changed, this should be sufficient. But if you want to detect *which fields* have changed, Craig Buckler has a decent article and example code at https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-form-change-checker/

Answer (score 0):

This explains it very clearly. [Generic way to detect if html form is edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959670/generic-way-to-detect-if-html-form-is-edited)

You add a data attribute to the form: `data-changed="false"`

```
<script   
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $("#myform :input").change(function() {
       //here we make sure that the on change event for every form input element
       //triggers the flag on the form (data-changed) to true.
       $("#myform").data("changed",true);
    });

    //when the form is being submitted:
    $(document).on('submit',"#myform",function(){
        if ($("#myform").data("changed")) {
        {
           //something has changed: do something
        }
    })
</script>

<form id="myform" name="myform" method="GET" data-changed="false">
   <!-- a bunch of text fields, etc -->
</form>
```